# \usepackage[subtle]{savetrees} uses more space than without importing package

Tags: spacing

When I tried to use savetrees, one paragraph in particular expands its text spacing significantly, but every other paragraph remains the same.
How do I prevent this?

[image: Text expands for one paragraph]

EDIT: While trying to produce an example I edited the document from this

```
Previous paragraph ....

[two blank lines]

\begin{figure}[]\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Blah Blah }
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
\label{Blah Blah }}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Sketch_3}
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah }
\end{figure}

[two blank lines]

Originally this wasn't thought to be an issue .... \\
\horrule{1pt}
{\sc Blah Blah }
```

to

```
Originally this wasn't thought to be an issue ....

[two blank lines]

\begin{figure}[]\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Blah Blah }
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
\label{Blah Blah }}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Sketch_3}
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah }
\end{figure}

\horrule{1pt}
{\sc Blah Blah }
```

And now it works so thanks for your advice.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please show a compilable example?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Posting a screenshot of your output doesn't really help us much without seeing the code you used to produce is. Can you construct a small self-contained document that reproduces the problem, and edit your question to show that.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Sure, will do

Comment: But I'm guessing that your problem is a duplicate of this one: [savetrees and \raggedright interact badly](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/319902)

Comment: I'm glad you seem to have solved your problem, but for future questions, please don't post code fragments, but as Phelype and I ask for, complete but minimal compilable documents. And just from the code you've posted, I can see a few bad practices. Don't use two letter font commands in LaTeX: see [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361) and don't use \\ to create a new paragraph: see [When to use \par and when \\, \newline, or blank lines](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664).

Comment: For a more general list see [What are the most common mistakes that beginners of (La)TeX and Friends make?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/139873)